# '550 The system cannot find the file specified' with using method request.urlopen for file on FTP

Tags: python, ftp, urllib, ftplib

Problem with encoding when i call request.urlopen() method.
Instance of ftplib.FTP() in urllib.request.ftpwrapper init() and retrfile() methods work with default latin-1 and i need to chose between utf-8 and cp1251
I see 3 ways:

1. Way i want, but don't know how.

Call request.urlopen() with param that contains encoding. And that encoding must be written to the self.ftp.encoding (ftplib.FTP())

2. Way I don't like.

Get file name encoding from ftp (ftp lib) and use it in request.urlopen(url.encode(file_name_encoding).decode('latin-1')).

**Problem description**.
I have a file with Cyrillic (rus) characters in its name.
Steps:

Connecting to FTP

```
con = ftplib.FTP()
con.connect(host, port)
con.login(username, password)
```

Getting files list

```
list_files = [_v for _v in self.con.nlst(_path)]
```

['Message.xml', 'Message_ÁÏ_TT.xml']

(For files Message.xml, Message_БП_TT.xml)

Fix it with using on the first step

```
con.encoding = 'utf-8'
con.sendcmd('OPTS UTF8 ON')
```

Then I need to use:

```
from urllib import request
url = 'ftp://login:password@ftpaddr:21/folder//Message_БП_TT.xml'
request.urlopen(url.encode().decode('latin-1'))
```

And then getting Exception:

**{URLError}<urlopen error ftp error: URLError("ftp error: error_perm('550 The system cannot find the file specified. ')")>**

In request lib there are init() and retrfile() where ftp connection initializing.
And i don't see the way how to change ftp default encoding "latin-1".

Use this method because with urllib.response.addinfourl parse heavy xml files.

P.S.
With some FTP this method works well and the file can be successfully read. And with some of them getting that exception. The reasons are not clear yet. And there is no way to get and analyze the FTP settings.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl. Hello. In general yes.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I don't like.

As i understand file name on FTP can be in utf-8 or in cp1251 (win-1251) encoding.
When ftplib initing with standard encode (latin-1) its will look like:

Message_ÐÐ_TT.xml - utf-8

Message_ÁÏ_TT.xml - cp1251

I don't know what encoding uses on ftp while making request, and always use utf-8 (encode()). So i don't like it, but it works:

```
try:
    return request.urlopen(url.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
except URLError:
    return request.urlopen(url.encode('cp1251').decode('latin-1'))
```

P.S. utf-8 under try for clarity